Blender 4.2 - how to change speed of animation several times
I am using Blender 4.2
I am working on simple animation project. What I need to do is to change speed of the object which follows the path (on the object is constraint for following the path) on several sections. So for example between frames 10 - 20 object should go slower, then from frames 40 - 70 should go faster and I would like to slow it down again between frames 90 - 100.
There are some solutions on the internet, but mostly for the older versions fo Blender - things obviously changed a lot between versions and I am having a hard time finding controls in latest version.
Is it possible to do this in Blender?
